# Recursive sum of digits of $1989^{1989}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

### It's a Big Sum Of Digits

From the 1989 Canadian Maths Olympiad:

> Define the sequence $\{a_n\}, n\ge1$ as follows:
>
> $a_n = \begin{cases}
>   1989^{1989}, & \text{if } n = 1, \\
>   \text{sum of digits in }a_{n-1}, & \text{if } n > 1.
> \end{cases}$
>
> What is the value of $a_5$?

---

Let $\sigma$ be the sum of digits function.

Have tried various approaches, but nothing seems promising:

- Factorised $1989 = 9 \cdot 221 = 9 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$, tried to find a pattern in digital sum of powers of 9, e.g. $\sigma(9) = 9, \sigma(9^2) = \sigma(81) = 9, \sigma(9^3)=\sigma(729)=18, \sigma(9^4)=\sigma(6561)=18, \\\sigma(9^5)=\sigma(59049)=27.$ 
  $\text{No pattern is evident, and the other factors have not even been included.}$
- Rewrote $1989 = 2000 - 11$ in an attempt to glean some information about the digital sum from the binomial expansion. Because of the large exponent, many of the coefficients overwhelm the powers of $2000$ and $11$, though.

Comment: **Estimate** $a_2, a_3,a_4,a_5$. Then use casting out $9$'s.

Comment: Surely you mean to define $a_n$ as the sum of the digits in $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: It helps to mention, $n\equiv \sigma(n)\mod 9$, and similarly $n\equiv \sigma^k(n)\mod 9$, so each of $a_1,a_2,\dots$ are equivalent modulo $9$.

Comment: @david-zhang - It's been redefined. Thanks.

Comment: Sum of digits is essentially a logarithm.  If you think the digits are "randomly distributed", the sum of digits of $n$ is about $4.5 \log_{10}(n)$.  Logs make numbers small very quickly.

Comment: Surprisingly it was a Question 3. Thin, and a mild variant of a standard problem.

Comment: More of a test of numeracy than of number theory per se. And even an innocuous looking number like $5^{5^5}$ is more than the upper estimate of atoms in the observable universe ($10^{82}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be the digit sum of positive integer $n$.

Then $f(1989^{1989}) \le 4 \times 1989 \times 9 < 100000$.

Thus $f^2(1989^{1989}) \le 5 \times 9 = 45$.

Thus $f^3(1989^{1989}) \le 2 \times 9 = 18$.

Thus $f^4(1989^{1989}) \le 9$.

Same for $f^5(1989^{1989})$.

Now all that remains is to find $1989^{1989} \bmod 9$.

Comment: Of course. And $1989 \equiv 0 (\mod 9)$. So $f^4(1989^{1989}) = 9 = a_5$.

Comment: @Marconius: Yea maybe they just wanted to make it easy to guess the answer even without calculating like I did.

Comment: How did you get that first estimate for $1989^{1989}$?

Comment: @RaceBannon $1989^{1989} < (10^4)^{1989}$.

Comment: So?  $10^4 > 1989$ but one has a sum of $1$ and the other has a sum of $27$.

Comment: @RaceBannon: Err.. The digit sum cannot exceed the number of digits times nine.

Comment: $0.3 < \log 2 < 0.302$ so $1989^{1989} < 2000^{2000} < 10^{3.302 \times 2000} = 10^{6604}$